# Configure VPS so only authenticated VPN users can access web server

Tags: iptables, openvpn, vpn, vps, ufw

I am setting up an intentionally vulnerable website to show some security stuff, but I don't want unauthorized people exploiting it. How would I be able to configure my VPS so that only people connected to the VPN (openvpn server) will be able to see the webpage, and everybody else just trying to access it on wan normally with no VPN cannot see it?

I have tried IPtables and ufw but I think I am screwing something up with syntax because I am unable to connect to the webpage even when authenticated, and allowing the lan subnet.

Users are on lan 10.8.0.0/24 and the website is running off the VPS's public IP ports 80 and 81.

Answer (score 0):

Block everything else to the webserver

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! -s 10.8.0.0/24,127.0.0.0/8 --dport 80 -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! -s 10.8.0.0/24,127.0.0.0/8 --dport 443 -j REJECT
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow only VPN ip on your VPS

```
iptables -A INPUT -d {VPN_IP} -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d {VPN_IP} -m tcp -p tcp --dport 81 -j ACCEPT
```